# Editable datas on button click

Tags: javascript, php, edit

How do i make all td rows from text appear a textbox on button click to edit data in db. Example:
[Before edit is clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYHAp.jpg)

[After edit is clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kC71N.png)

Comment: show us your try first. What you have tried to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to your table. When you click on a row, iterate through each cell in that row.

If there is no `input` elemenet, then get the content of the cell, clear the content and add an `input` element with the text.

Here is a working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wc8bbybp/).

Warning: you should handle the name of the input values, and you should care about html tags in the value of the cells, if there are not only pure texts.

**HTML**

```
    <table class="editable" style="border: 1px solid #000; border-collapse: collapse">
    <tr>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #000; padding: 10px;">This is a text</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #000; padding: 10px;">Another text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('table.editable').on('click', 'tr', function () {
    $(this).find('td').each(function () {
        if ($(this).find('input').length < 1) {
        let html = $(this).html();
                $(this).empty();
        $(this).append('<input name="value[]" value="' + html + '" />');
        }
    });
});
```